# How to change the div col order in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the stack order of the div col's in Twitter Bootstrap in mobile view. I would like the text in col-md-7 to be pulled on top of the image in col-md-5 in mobile view, but when viewing on desktop the div col's stay the same.

Here is the code I am using

```
  <div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/O7KC6ak.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a Bootly demo of what I'm trying to accomplish
[Bootly demo](http://bootply.com/83441)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One kind of ugly way to do this is to think mobile first. Order the columns how you want them to stack for xs/sm, and then use pull and push to reorder them for larger screens. Something like this should work:

```
  <div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/O7KC6ak.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
  </div>
```

(I would have tested it, but your demo link just leads to an error message and I'm too lazy to make my own demo.)

Comment: My demo works for me, was bootly down? Also this works perfectly. I don't think its ugly at all, changing the order of the text/image was the best way!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following push and pull classes:

```
<div class="row featurette">
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-7">
  <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/O7KC6ak.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-pull-5">
  <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
  <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
</div>
```

You can read more on bootstrap 3's [CSS documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: I should have been more clear, I want the divs to stack only in mobile view. I want the current layout to stay the same. So the text should stack on top of the image (col-md-7 on top of col-md-5)